# javascript/backbone events when model changed

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

I'm having an architecture difficulty with application designed in Backbone.

I've got cascaded, **hierarchical views**, i.e. root view has header, middle and footer views. Each of them consists of some lower level views, e.g. header view consists of tabs, preferences and login/logout views. It's just a view aggregation.

I also have a **configuration model**, which has several attributes, it's loaded via AJAX (standard backbone fetch). The model attributes are displayed in the interface using popups, menus etc. to enable the user to choose his settings. When the user changes a setting, possibly many parts of the app will have to re-render. The configuration model holds "state" properties (e.g. property `currentPeriod` is used among `periods` which were fetched via AJAX)

Inside views, I use `listenTo(this.model, 'change:currentPeriod', this.render)` to make this view **re-render when anything is changed** in the configuration.

I set all my default state attributes inside model::`parse`. The problem is that if I have 10 attributes to set (after parse is over) and probably each of them will trigger some events, many of them will be run multiple times (which is not what I want).

I was looking for a possibility to set current state attributes inside parse with the {silent:true} option - then no events would be triggered. I hope some of you already had the same problem and there exists an easy solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. You mention using `{silent:true}` when you call `set`, to prevent change events; isn't that what you want?

Comment: @freejosh, no. I can use x.set('xxx', value, {silent: true}). But I need the same thing inside the `parse` function which returned value is being `set` after the parse function is over. Or if there is a better solution, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either fire all events "onSet"/"onChange" or none; in other words, you can pass `silent: true`, or not, but it's a binary choice.  You can't say "set foo, and by the way only fire off this event, not that one".

If you want that level of control I'd recommend using `silent: true` and then manually triggering the events you do want.

If that doesn't work for you, I'd recommend changing how you bind your events, so that you only bind a given event once; that way it won't repeat.  And if *that* doesn't work, you can just make your render method work even if it's run multiple times; that way the event can trigger render multiple times, but it won't hurt anything.

Comment: I guess I have the last option you wrote, but I'm rendering a tree with few hundred nodes and it takes a lot of time if it's fired multiple times.

I am thinking of using `this.attributes.currentPeriod = value` inside `parse` function just to "trick" backbone not to fire the event when the attribute is initialized for the first time. What do you think?

Comment: That seems reasonable, and the Backbone docs seem to encourage this approach: "Note that [silent: true] is rarely, perhaps even never, a good idea. Passing through a specific flag in the options for your event callback to look at, and choose to ignore, will usually work out better."  One other thought: you could also use 'reset' and 'change' events to better target some of your handlers.

Answer (score 0):

During `fetch` the reference to `options` remains the same between `parse` and `set`, so you could change the value of `options.silent` and the changes will carry over.

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CKACt/1/) for an example of this working.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create a proxy (a bare `Backbone.Events` object) and have your views listen to it. The proxy object would listen to `all` on the model and simply queue up the events fired by the model (eliminating duplicative events) until the model fires an "I'm done" event (which you'd trigger at the end of `parse`); then the proxy would fire off all the queued events and flush the queue.